# Element not move when animation happens

Tags: html, css, animation, text

So, I'm learning CSS and JS now, and I'm trying to make a line of text where the first part of the text get animated, and the second don't, but when I do it, the second text moves cause the first changed.

HTML:

```
<div class="AnimatedText"><span class="wiggle1">F</span><span class="wiggle2">i</span><span class="wiggle3">r</span><span class="wiggle1">s</span><span class="wiggle2">t</span><span class="wiggle3">T</span><span class="wiggle1">e</span><span class="wiggle2">x</span><span class="wiggle3">T</span><span class="text1"> second text.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.AnimatedText {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  }

.wiggle1 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s linear; 
  animation: mymove 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wiggle2 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove1 1s linear; 
  animation: mymove1 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wiggle3 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove2 1s linear; 
  animation: mymove2 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text1 {
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {font-size: 100%;}
    25% {font-size: 120%;}
    50% {font-size: 140%;}
    75% {font-size: 130%;}
    100% {font-size: 100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove1 {
    0%   {font-size: 120%;}
    25% {font-size: 140%;}
    50% {font-size: 120%;}
    75% {font-size: 100%;}
    100% {font-size: 120%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove2 {
    0%   {font-size: 140%;}
    25% {font-size: 120%;}
    50% {font-size: 100%;}
    75% {font-size: 120%;}
    100% {font-size: 140%;}
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/udmm8aqp/)**

I did set the position of the second text to absolute, then it resulted to fixed the vertical position, but it still goes to the side.
How can I make the second text stay on the same place, without moving?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `left:` or `right:` value. This will prevent the text from being moved.